# I can't run Ethereum Wallet /Mist 0.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mist

I can't run Ethereum Wallet /Mist 0.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 using the release files 
https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Error messages:

> ./Ethereum-Wallet: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> ./Mist: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Additional package is required

sudo apt-get install libnss3